# How to ensure single version of dependency in consuming application

Tags: logging, npm, aurelia, package.json

I'm using `peerDependencies` for this purpose, but wonder is it sufficient or not, or it is just not possible.

Using [`aurelia-logging`](https://github.com/aurelia/logging), as an example.

I created a library, `library-a`, which uses `aurelia-logging` to do some logging.

For normal dependencies, I would just add it as `dependencies`.
However, `aurelia-logging` contain some global state (i.e. storing all loggers created) so that it exposes a `setLevel()` function which can set the logLevel of all loggers.

Due to this global state, the end application needs to use a single version of `aurelia-logging` for the whole thing to work.
If not, some modules may use a different version (thus a different instance) of `aurelia-logging` and the `setLevel()` function does not work correctly.

As a library author, I'm listing `aurelia-logging` as a `dependencies` as well as a `peerDependencies`.

Would it do what I wanted it to do?

Global state is general is a bad idea, but in this case, there seems to be no other way out of it.

Comment: My guess is I need `flat` mode supported in `yarn` for this purpose. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I think more about it, the solution is to have a version locked module to store these "global states".

DISCLAIMER: You should avoid using global states as much as possible.

I have created https://github.com/unional/global-store for this purpose.

DISCLAIMER AGAIN: Only use it if you know that you are doing the right thing. Read the README. :)